# Sending e-mail with attachment via cron

Tags: bash, cron

I want my Raspberry Pi at home to send me an e-mail with my current todo list.
I'm managing my todos with a tool called [taskworrior](http://taskwarrior.org/projects/show/taskwarrior).
I wrote a bash script, writing my task into a file and sending my this file:

```
#!/bin/bash
task > /home/pi/tasks.txt
sendEmail -f info@pi.home -t myemail@gmail.com -u Tasks -m "See attachment" -a /home/pi/tasks.txt -s smtp-server -xu user -xp password
```

This script works perfectly fine, if I call it from the command line.
The command "task" just prints my todos into a file in this case.

Additionally I added a cron job:

```
0 4 * * * /home/pi/scripts/sendtasks
```

This cron job however only sends me an e-mail with an empty attachment. Also, if I ssh to my pi I only find an empty file there.
So I'm assuming task is called by some "cron-user" and therefore doesn't output my tasks. However, I added the cron job in my personal crontab (user "pi").

Any ideas what I can do about that?

Comment: "So I'm assuming task is called by some 'cron-user'":  Don't assume.  Check in /var/log for messages.  You can also check the ownership of tasks.txt file.   Also, cron runs under a restricted environment.  You may need to set a PATH to assure that bash can find it.

Comment: Damn, I hate spending all that time on stupid mistakes: You're right, the task command wasn't found due to the directory not being in the PATH variable when running the cron job... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons of security, the default PATH under cron is set to "/usr/bin:/bin".  That is quite restricted.  You can define a more inclusive PATH either at the beginning of your crontab file or at the beginning of your script.  For best security, though, just specify full paths everywhere.